# serving a directory of .html and .css in flask w/o specifying each file w/routes

Tags: flask

how can i serve a directory of .html and .css in flask?  my directory structure looks like the following:

```
./docs/             # contains html
./docs/_static      # contains .css and images
```

i'd like to specify the file ./docs/index.html with the route:

```
@app.route('/docs/')
def documentation():
    return render_template('docs/index.html')
```

and have all links to and from index.html that are contained within ./docs to be accessible without having to explicitly specify them with @app.route.  any idea if/how this can be done?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to put all your static files in a folder named `static` and all templates in a folder named `templates`. So your folder structure should look like this:

```
/docs/static/here_your_css_and_js_files
/docs/templates/here_your_html_files
```

To include your `.css` and `.js` files in your html your have to add in the head your html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
```

The `.html` files are automatically founded by flask if you put them in the `templates` directory.

Comment: i was really hoping to not have to update each and every .html file with the new relative static location.  these files will change often, and if this is the solution, it will definitely need automation.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create your routes, or even create a custom view and walk through your docs directory and setup custom routes and template names. Something like this should work for you:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.views import View

HOME_BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
TEMPLATE_BASE = os.path.join(HOME_BASE, 'templates')
TEMPLATE_BASE_LEN = len(TEMPLATE_BASE)

class CustomTemplateView(View):

    def __init__(self, template_name):
        self.template_name = template_name

    def dispatch_request(self):
        return render_template(self.template_name)

app = Flask(__name__)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(TEMPLATE_BASE, 'docs')):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.html'):
            template_name = os.path.join(root, file)[TEMPLATE_BASE_LEN:]
            doc_path = os.path.splitext(template_name)[0]
            app.add_url_rule(doc_path, view_func = CustomTemplateView.as_view(
                doc_path.replace('/', '_'), template_name = template_name[1:]))
```

This code assumes that your docs directory layout looks like this:

```
yourproject/__init__.py
yourproject/templates/docs/403.html
yourproject/templates/docs/404.html
yourproject/templates/docs/accounts/add.html
yourproject/templates/docs/accounts/edit.html
yourproject/templates/docs/accounts/groups/template1.html
yourproject/templates/docs/accounts/index.html
yourproject/templates/docs/accounts/users/index.html
yourproject/templates/docs/accounts/users/template1.html
yourproject/templates/docs/accounts/users/template2.html
...
```

The code above should go into `__init__.py` file.